# parse JSON in groovy to get values (python dict)

Tags: python, json, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a dictionary that I get as a python dictionary in groovy which I then assign to a variable x :

```
def x = "{'JIRACHEF': 'PIBEP-2135', 'JIRADEPLOYER': 'PIBEP-2136', 'JIRASINGLEBUILD': 'PIBEP-2137'}"
```

I want to parse the above and get values for :

- JIRACHEF
- JIRADEPLOYER
- JIRASINGLEBUILD

whats the most elegant groovy way of doing it ?

Comment: What exactly do you need? Assign variables values?

Comment: @sisanared - how to go about doing that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the LAX slurper (in recent versions of Groovy):

```
import groovy.json.*

def x = "{'JIRACHEF': 'PIBEP-2135', 'JIRADEPLOYER': 'PIBEP-2136', 'JIRASINGLEBUILD': 'PIBEP-2137'}"

def parsed = new JsonSlurper().setType(JsonParserType.LAX).parseText(x)

println parsed.JIRACHEF
println parsed.JIRADEPLOYER
println parsed.JIRASINGLEBUILD
```