# Parse flat file python dict into groovy

Tags: groovy

I'm fairly new to Groovy and I have a flat file that is in Python. It doesn't contain any code, it just generates a Python dictionary.

So the Python looks similar to:

```
bob = {}
bob["names"] = []
bob["names"][0] = {}
bob["names"][0]["nick"] = "wobbly bob"
```

which just defines the dict.

I am currently parsing the code in groovy using a lot of splits, replaces and conditionals to turn it into something, it works, but I can't help thinking there MUST be a more elegant way.

So does anyone know of a good groovy library I could use to parse this kind of information?

Comment: I looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41680219/parse-json-in-groovy-to-get-values-python-dict but it's not the same kind of case. That looks like an in-memory dict which does look like JSON, this sadly doesn't.

Comment: Running your python example causes error https://gist.github.com/wololock/90125cada9fb6a0a4be5474c1383ffa4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run your Python script from inside a Groovy script. Take a look at following example:

**test.py**

```
bob = {"names":[{"nick": "wobbly bob"}]}
print(bob)
```

> **Important**: your script has to produce any output so Groovy can parse it. That's why I put `print(bob)` in the end of the script.

**test.groovy**

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonParserType

def cmd = ["python", "test.py"]

def result = cmd.execute()

def json = new JsonSlurper().setType(JsonParserType.LAX).parseText(result.text)

println json
```

> For simplicity both files have to be placed in the same folder.

Running `groovy test.groovy` produces following output:

```
[names:[[nick:wobbly bob]]]
```

Keep in mind that Python script generates following output:

```
{'names': [{'nick': 'wobbly bob'}]}
```

That's why we call `.setType(JsonParserType.LAX)` (credits to [tim_yates](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6509/tim-yates) for suggesting this approach instead of replacing all single quotes with double quotes) to accept single quotes as well, otherwise Groovy will complain:

```
Caught: groovy.json.JsonException: expecting '}' or ',' but got current char ''' with an int value of 39

The current character read is ''' with an int value of 39
expecting '}' or ',' but got current char ''' with an int value of 39
line number 1
index number 1
{'names': [{'nick': 'wobbly bob'}]}
.^
groovy.json.JsonException: expecting '}' or ',' but got current char ''' with an int value of 39

The current character read is ''' with an int value of 39
expecting '}' or ',' but got current char ''' with an int value of 39
line number 1
index number 1
{'names': [{'nick': 'wobbly bob'}]}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: You can also `import groovy.json.JsonParserType`, and then just do:  `new JsonSlurper().setType(JsonParserType.LAX).parseText(result)` (without the need for character substitution)

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. Sorry about the example not working.. typed from memory